# Stack Exchange team: Some older SharePoint Overflow users have incorrectly low reputation?

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, reputation

I found [a user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/756/getsmiles), who had 6 reputation even though they've had many votes. I performed a reputation recalc and sure enough they received 108. Here's [another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/685/dmce) [and another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/968/vivek) (no recalcs done).

It looks like these are older users they have not logged in since the site was migrated. They're only showing votes received since the migration.

Do we need a site-wide reputation recalc?

Comment: I believe my rep went down when they did the migration.  I think I had about 100 rep on the old site so this seemed odd to me.  Not sure if it's related, but worth mentioning.

Comment: We're taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've done a site-wide rep recalc to clean this up.

Comment: What triggers someones rep being recalculated? My rep is still much lower than it was in the old site?